# Anaconda environment as an folder

Tags: python, batch-file, anaconda, spyder, environment

I want to have a special environment for a customer of a company. Therefore
I have some kind of requirements.txt file, in which the costumer can install the environment with an .bat file like:

`conda create -env -name -req.txt ...`

My question is if its also possible to drop the environment I use as a folder inside the software. I mean, can his Anaconda detect the environment inside the folder then or can he even ran it without having Anaconda on his computer, as the python kernel seems to be in any environment folder?

Thank you and best regards!

Comment: See [Conda Pack](https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/).